# Search feature Stream refactoring

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
  SearchService().searchByName(value, context).then((QuerySnapshot docs) {
```

I'm trying to refactor this as I've changed `SearchService()` to a Stream.

`.then` gives, of course, `The method '.then' isn't defined for the type 'Stream'`.

A very 'novice' quesiton, but I'm not sure the correct way to rewrite this for a Stream?

```
if (queryResultSet.length == 0 && value.length == 1) {
  SearchService().searchByName(value, context).then((QuerySnapshot docs) {
    for (int i = 0; i < docs.docs.length; ++i) {
      queryResultSet.add(docs.docs[i].data());
    }
  });
```

.

```
class SearchService {
Stream<QuerySnapshot> searchByName(
  String searchField, BuildContext context) async* {
final uid = await TheProvider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
yield* FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("userData")
    .doc(uid)
    .collection("Contacts")
    .where('searchKey',
        isEqualTo: searchField.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase())
    .snapshots();
}
}
```

Comment: Read this: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams

Comment: @julemand101 I have

Comment: Ok, did you learn that your question does not make much sense since a Stream is a potential endless sequence of events and not just a single value like Future? So for streams you are going to subscribe for events using e.g. listen.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what would expect to happen if you called `then` on a Stream.  `then` is used with Futures to get a single value for a single operation.  Streams produces multiple values over time.  So they are not really compatible concepts.

Comment: @DougStevenson 


I've clarified the question a bit more

Comment: As has been mentioned in comments a couple times, Streams and Futures are not compatible concepts.  It's not a simple "rewrite".  And without seeing what `SearchService().searchByName()` does, we can't really tell you what you need to do.  You're going to have to figure out what you need from the stream that is a single value rather that a sequence of values - we don't know what you need.

Comment: @DougStevenson I did initally think it'd be a "change `.then` to `.listen`" type of answer but I understand that it's not now, thank you. I've added `SearchService().searchByName()` to the question for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single result from a database query instead of a stream of results that change over time, use `get()` instead of `snapshots()`.  It will return a Future that works the way you expect.  This is illustrated in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querysnapshot).

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("userData")
    .doc(uid)
    .collection("Contacts")
    .where('searchKey',
        isEqualTo: searchField.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase())
    .get();
```